# Ranking items by the magnitude of their effect on dissimilarity?

Tags: machine-learning, python, distance, recommender-system, similarities

[reposting with more detail, after previous question was removed due to lack of detail or clarity]

I am working on getting a better understanding of my company's user base. We have distinct independent groups using our product and I'd like to know how similar / dissimilar they are, and in what way. This will inform what features we want to build next - and to which sub group.

Assume, for example, I have two people who each watched a 1000 films and gave each a rating of 1 to 5. Now I have a vector of length 1000 for each person. I calculate the cosine similarity between the two.

I'd like to learn how dissimilar those users are, so would like to rank the 1000 films by most contributing to dissimilarity to least. How can I do that? Preferably with Python :)

Thanks

Comment: Your language is misleading: *you* deleted your previous post and reposted it here to circumvent its closure.  Please read our [help] for information on how this site works and how it is moderated.

Comment: @whuber I don't think I'm in the wrong. The message I got when that post was closed was that it's missing details. I added the first paragraph for context. That same message also said I can repost.